# Maximum update depth exceeded. Infinite redirects and how to better structure my routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

First off, I'm very new to React so forgive my very basic question. I have my App component housing my React Router routes, and want to redirect to the login page if no authorised user is found but I'm getting the error 'Maximum update depth exceeded.'.

I (think I) understand that react is caught in an infinite loop of trying to redirect to /login, but can't really think of a cleaner way of addressing the issue / restructuring.

Initially my fix was to call redirectToLogin() which would set state.redirectToLogin so when it redirected it didn't try to again. While this worked I read a few comments elsewhere that stated setting state in the render function is a big no-no.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Loading } from './components/loading/Loading';
import { Navbar } from './components/navbar/Navbar';
import AuthService from './services/auth-service';

import { Users } from './components/users/Users';
import { UsersCreate } from './components/users/users-create/UsersCreate';
import { Login } from './components/auth/Login';

import './App.scss';
import './styles/variables.scss';

type State = {
  loading: boolean,
  authenticated: boolean,
  redirectToLogin: boolean
}

class App extends Component<{}, State> {

  authService: AuthService;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.authService = new AuthService();
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      authenticated: false,
      redirectToLogin: false
    };

    // this.redirectToLogin = this.redirectToLogin.bind(this);

    // Intercept 401 responses and redirect to login
    AuthService.registerUnauthenticatedInterceptor();

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Check if user is authenticated
    if (AuthService.getUser()) {
      this.setState({
        authenticated: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        redirectToLogin: true
      })
    }
    this.setState<any>({ loading: false });
  }

  // redirectToLogin() {
  //   this.setState({
  //     redirectToLogin: false
  //   });
  //   return <Redirect to="/login" />
  // }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Loading />
    }
    if (!this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Router>

            {
              this.state.authenticated ?
              <Navbar /> : null
            }
            {
              !this.state.authenticated && this.state.redirectToLogin ?
              <Redirect to="/login" /> : null
            }

            <Route exact path="/login" render={() => <Login />} />

            <div className="component-page">
              <div className="container-fluid">

                <Route exact path="/users" render={() => <Users />} />
                <Route exact path="/users/create" render={() => <UsersCreate />} />

              </div>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm hoping there's an easy fix that I'm missing but I'm open to restructuring if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: "Maximum update depth exceeded" this problem occurs when there is an infinite loop occurs. You need to provide other components to recognize where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
{
    !this.state.authenticated && this.state.redirectToLogin ?
    <Redirect to="/login" /> : null
}
```

If the page success to redirect to "/login", this same component App is rendered right? Then componentDidUpdate() will again evaluate to the same result, and redirect will trigger again, in an infinite loop.

Since no matter this.state.authenticated is true or not, you will still be at the same App component, so before redirect, you need to check if you are already at "/login" or not.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    // Check if user is authenticated
    if (AuthService.getUser()) {
      this.setState({
        authenticated: true
      });
    } else {
      if (this.props.location.pathname != '/login') {
         this.setState({
           redirectToLogin: true
         })
      }
    }
    this.setState<any>({ loading: false });
  }
```

Comment: Turns out componentDidMount isn't called again on re-render but componentDidUpdate is. So I've used this method to check wether the redirect has happened and to prevent it from happening again. If you update to componentDidUpdate() I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay, thanks for your feedback. Changed the answer as you suggested.